# Sanitize Disqus API results?

Tags: api, sanitization, disqus

Can I trust the results from the Disqus API, not to include evil scripts? Can I find information somewhere. Would you sanitize the JSON data, that is returned? Official answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the body of a comment, there's nothing to worry about. We already sanitize comment and thread messages.

Comment: Just to add to this, I use the raw result in my plugin and haven't had any issues.